NPM Install in Downstream Pipeline Triggering Upstream Project
I'm working with a multi-project CI/CD setup and I'm encountering an issue with my downstream pipeline. I have configured a trigger to include a downstream project as follows:
trigger: include: - project: downstream-project-path ref: branchname file: ci/integration_test.yml strategy: depend
However, when I run npm install in the downstream pipeline, it appears to be executing npm install in the upstream project instead.
Question: How can I ensure that the npm install command in my downstream pipeline runs independently of the upstream project? Is there a specific configuration I need to adjust in my CI/CD setup?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I tried using git strategy: clone and checkout: true, in downstream job but this did not resolve the issue.
I expected that after triggering the downstream pipeline, running npm install in the downstream project would execute within the context of the downstream project. However, the current working directory (pwd) still shows that I am in the upstream project directory.
